# Linear regression in R with data from Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, excel, linear-regression

I want to import data from MS Sql Server and apply linear regression on the data in R. But i am not sure how i can manipulate the data from sql server so that i can do a regression. My table in sql server looks like this,

```
Pack    Cubes   Name    Sales
1001    1.2      A      10
1001    1.2      B      12
1002    0.9      A      8
1002    0.9      B      5
1002    0.9      C      12
1003    1.5      A      5
1003    1.5      C      10
1004    0.8      B      8
1004    0.8      C      10
1005    1.3      A      5
1005    1.3      B      8
1005    1.3      C      12
```

If i would manipulate the data in excel for a regression model it would looks like this,

```
Cubes   A   B   C
1.2    10   12  0
0.9    8    5   12
1.5    5    0   10
0.8    0    8   10
1.3    5    8   12
```

The A, B, C is my dependent variables and Cubes my independent variable. The Pack in my sql table is just a reference. My Sql connection to a DSN looks like this (which works perfectly),

```
library(RODBC)
myconn <- odbcConnect("sqlserver")
data <- sqlQuery(myconn,"select Cubes,Name,Sales from mytable")
```

With the regression i tried (which is wrong),

```
summary(data)
reg<-lm(Cubes~Sales,data)
summary(reg)
```

How can i manipulate the data from sql server as i would if i did it in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reshape or the reshape package:

```
wide <- reshape(data, v.names = "Sales", idvar = "Cubes",
            timevar = "Name", direction = "wide")
```

Comment: +1, although to get exactly what the OP asked for, you need to replace the `NA` by 0.

Comment: Thanks, reshape works, i just added wide[is.na(wide)]=0 that makes the NAs equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package. Note that `dcast` leads to `NA` for non-existing combinations of `Name` and `Sales`. You need to manually change this to `0`:

```
res = dcast(df, Cubes ~ Name, value.var = 'Sales')
res[is.na(res)] = 0
res
  Cubes  A  B  C
1   0.8  0  8 10
2   0.9  8  5 12
3   1.2 10 12  0
4   1.3  5  8 12
5   1.5  5  0 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from SQL Server directly in the format you need by using an SQL as follows:

```
   SELECT Cubes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='A' then Sales else 0 END) A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='B' then Sales else 0 END) B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='C' then Sales else 0 END) C
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY Cubes
```